# Create a long live token for Azure with only Login Server, Username and Password

Tags: azure, curl, command-line-interface

Is it there a way to create a long Authorization token knowing only Login Server (.e.g: somename.azurecr.io) Username and Password (these credentials are used to login to Docker and push/pull/etc images to the Azure Registry) ?

Also, is it there a way to find all tags to a specific image with only these data?

Thank you,

Comment: isn't it better and safer to - login- do the acr operations - logout instead of having a long living auth token?

Comment: Maybe it is ... my goal is actually finding all tags for a specific image without installing az cli

Comment: Yeey ... founded ... it seems that the V2 api that's available for Docker Registry API can be used here as well ... e.g.: curl -L -u user:pass https://somename.azurecr.io/v2/name_of_image/tags/list

Comment: thats good to know